# .htaccess windows issue

Tags: php, windows, apache, .htaccess

In the root directory of a small site i'm developing i have the following .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-F
RewriteRule .$ index.php
```

that basically allows me to have pretty urls as it remaps every path *that does not exists* on the server (eg : /user/details/145 ) as a call to index.php where I handle it MVC-style.

While this works ok on MacOs, this morning I have to work on another machine that has Windows (the apache server is run by [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)) and it does not work as it seems to redirect **all** the calls (eg those to static files like images) to index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-f  not -F
got this in 5 seconds from http://www.google.ru/search?q=rewritecond